# The $ref doesn't work inside Vuetify elements

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, ref

I've created a Vue component with Vuetify to be a CarouselItem

*LandingPageCarouselItem.vue*

```
<template>
    <v-carousel-item>

        <v-img
            :lazy-src="item.image.sizes.landing_carousel_bg_xs"
            :src="item.image.sizes.landing_carousel_bg_fhd">

            <div ref="carousel_html" style="height: 100%" class="html"></div>

        </v-img>

    </v-carousel-item>
    
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ["item"],
    data: () => ({
        html: undefined,
    }),
    created() {
        this.html = Base64.decode(this.item.html)
    },
    mounted() {
        this.$refs.carousel_html.innerHTML = this.html // this causes an error

    }
}
</script>
```

*LandingPage.vue*

```
...
<v-carousel>

   <landing-page-carousel-item
       v-for="(item,i) in page_data.front_page.main_view.carousel_items"
       :key="i"
       :item="item">

   </landing-page-carousel-item>

</v-carousel>
...
```

However, for 3 items that my API provides, only first is rendered corectly. The others scream about an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'innerHTML')
```

What's interesting, when `div.html` isn't inside Vuetify component, it works fine.
Like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <v-carousel-item>
            <v-img
                :lazy-src="item.image.sizes.landing_carousel_bg_xs"
                :src="item.image.sizes.landing_carousel_bg_fhd">
            </v-img>
        </v-carousel-item>
        <div ref="carousel_html" style="height: 100%" class="html"></div>
    </div>
</template>
```

But I can't do this due to Vuetify requirements.

**I have no idea how to solve this problem. But I have to put custom HTML inside div.html.**

Comment: What do you have inside of `this.$refs.carousel_html`?

Comment: But do you have what you expect when console.logging it?

Comment: @kissu sorry, for 1st item `this.$refs.carousel_html` is a correct reference, but for others this.$refs is empty

Comment: v-img doesn't have a default slot don't mess with innerHTML, instead make it `<v-carousel-item><div class="img-wrap"><v-img /> <div class="html">...</div></div>` then make `.img-wrap` relative positioning and `.html` absolute to place the text over the image

Comment: @LawrenceCherone    Unfortunately, `<v-carousel-item><div style="height: 100%"><v-img/><div ref="carousel_html" style="height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%"></div></div></v-carousel-item>` did not work. It causes the same error.

Comment: it shouldn't be the same error if you removed `this.$refs.carousel_html.innerHTML = this.html`, can you make a verifiable example, additionally the first div needs be relative for it to work

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-template-forked-s2t0yw?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: Gracias amigo <3. Thanks a lot. I didn't know about v-html.